# Regular Expression - matching file extension from a URL

Tags: ruby, regex

So I have a very specific URL, that tends to always follow the following format:

`http://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/0DCB6FF2EF1179983941847883776_38a153447e7.1.5.3901866229871838946.mp4?versionId=.k9_w6W7t1Yr1KUCWRIm6AnYhSdOUz32`

Basically I want to grab everything from after the `.` and before the `?versionId` as I imagine that's the consistent location of the file extension.

I currently have something like this where `\.\.{0}(.+)\?versionId` it is matching everything starting from the first `.` to `versionId`.

One solution I thought about doing was using the `.` as a delimiter. I've never tried to restrict a character, but basically I would want it to try to match everything starting with a `.`, reject anything that has a `.` leading up to the `?`.

Anyone got any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your goal to get 'mp4'? Might consider not using a regex at all...

```
> require 'uri'
> uri = URI.parse('http://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/0DCB6FF2EF1179983941847883776_38a153447e7.1.5.3901866229871838946.mp4?versionId=.k9_w6W7t1Yr1KUCWRIm6AnYhSdOUz32')
=> #<URI::HTTP http://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/0DCB6FF2EF1179983941847883776_38a153447e7.1.5.3901866229871838946.mp4?versionId=.k9_w6W7t1Yr1KUCWRIm6AnYhSdOUz32>
> uri.path
=> "/r/videos/0DCB6FF2EF1179983941847883776_38a153447e7.1.5.3901866229871838946.mp4"
> File.extname(uri.path)
=> ".mp4"
```

Comment: Oh that's much better. Guess I can close my Rubular tab now.

Answer (score 0):

Completely in agreement with Philip Hallstrom, this is a typical XY problem. However, if you really wish to just hone your Regexp skills, the literal solution to your question is ([Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/XyFiH3nU5z)):

```
(?<=\.)[^.]+(?=\?)
```

"From where a period was just before, match any number of non-periods, matching up to where question mark is just after."

To understand this, read up on positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`), positive lookahead (`(?=...)`), and negated character sets (`[^...]`).